# Compact camera under $300 manual controls

Tags: camera

I'm looking for a compact digital camera with manual controls.

---

### Requirements

- **Price<sup>1</sup>**: As low as possible
- **Flash, SD Card Slot**
- **Maximum Size<sup>2</sup>**: 6 x 5 x 2 inches
- **Manual Control**: Aperture, ISO, Shutter speed
- **Specifications**

  - **Minimum Aperture**: f/2.8
  - **Picture Resolution**: 12MP
  - **Video Resolution:** 1280 x 720 @ 24p
  - **Microphone**: any quality
  - **Shutter Speed:** 1/2000 sec - 30 secs
  - **Zoom**: 5x optical

---

### Preferences

<sup>Lower Number is Higher Priority</sup>

- **RAW Images (1)**
- **Specifications**

  - **Picture Resolution (2)**: 20MP
  - **Shutter Speed (3)**: 1/2000 sec - infinite
  - **Zoom (4)**: 20x optical
  - **Video Resolution**: (5) 1920 x 1080 / (7) 3840 x 2160
  - **Video Framerate (6)**: 60p
- **Interchangeable lenses<sup>3</sup> (8)**

---

### Not Necessary

<sup>But fine to have!</sup>

- Touchscreen
- HDMI/VGA/DVI/Other output
- Internal storage
- WiFi

---

<sup>**1**</sup>Please post other cameras fitting the preferences above the budget for others who stumble upon this post
<sup>**2**</sup>Flexible
<sup>**3**</sup>Consider the price of a decent lens when comparing to alternatives with fixed lenses, up to your discretion

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in the camera world, I would say that a lot of these features are exclusive to dslr.

Comment: I've managed to find the Pentax XG-1. I'm going to look at it a bit more tomorrow, but so far it looks like it fills all your requirements

Comment: There are a couple of others just outside your price range, like the Panasonic FZ80, but I'm fairly sure the Pentax is the best match you're going to get under $300

Comment: @EdwardNunn, bulb mode and interchangeable lenses are pretty much exclusive to DSLRs, but the rest of the features can be found on (or added to, in the case of Canon) mid-range to high-end point-and-shoot cameras.

Comment: The problem with DSLRs is their size and pricing both do not fit my requirements.

Comment: I disagree with the pricing there, the Canon EOS 700D / Rebel T5i is closer to your price point with a lens, than the suggestion below. It's also a very good camera, even coming on for light professional usage.

Comment: @EdwardNunn the EOS 700D is very expensive also ($500+ for body and 18-55mm lens)

Comment: @RubyJunk That's very strange, I paid 375 two years ago for the body and lens kit

Answer (score 1):

I have the [Nikon 1 J5](https://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/digital-cameras/nikon-1/everyday/nikon-1-j5) and I get some great photos out of it.

It's around $300 and comes with loads of in-camera effects (toy camera, wide angle, colour selection so on) and considering it's a mirror-less camera it captures really hi-res photos, plus its not a pain to lug around!

Comment: This camera starts at $500 in the U.S., but I'll definitely be looking at used models of this since it fits my criteria. EDIT: That is, with a lens.

Comment: @RubyJunk if you end up getting one I couldn't recommend it more!